# How to get to one key by searching multiple values ​assigned to one key in python?

Tags: python, selenium, dictionary, appium

I have a problem. I'm using sellenium and appium in python durring desktop testing, and I have a problem:

I have to click one button among the many buttons. However, sometimes these buttons are hidden and I have to click on a specific button category first, before they show up.I put buttons and categories in the dictionary:

`categories = {'CATEGORY_1': ['Button1_1', 'Button1_2', 'Button1_3'], 'CATEGORY_2': ['Button2_1', 'Button2_2', 'Button2_3']}`

Now I want to click a specific button, but if it doesn't appear, click the appropriate category, then click the button. Once the click is done, I check if there is a valid tab, specified in a separate dictionary.

I wrote something like this:

```
        if driver.find_elements_by_name(button):
            try:
                Methods.click(self, driver, button)
                for key, value in Modules.buttons.items():
                    if key == button:
                        self.tab = value
                        Methods.findNameInClass(driver, "TabsControl", self.tab)
            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass
        else:
            for key, values in Modules.categories.items():
                if button in values:
                    Methods.click(self, driver, key)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is "Modules.buttons" the equivalent dictionary for "categories"? You're clicking, for example, 'Button1_1', and if that doesn't work, you want to click 'CATEGORY_1'? If so, first, you can't do an '==' comparison. Your values are a list, so you should use 'if button in values'

Comment: "Modules.buttons" is dictonary with buttons as keys and tab names as values, eg. ```buttons = {'Button1_1': 'TabName1', 'Button1_2': 'TabName2'}```. I change my comparison to 'if button in values' but it doesn't work now too :/

Comment: Ok, problem solved. I changed square brackets to curly brackets in my categories dictionary, and now it works. Thanks!